# How to sum/multiply a split of an item in a listbox?

Tags: vb.net, vba

So I am making a program in which you can select products from a combo box, select the quantity and it will return with the price and the quantity in a list box.

However, I want to be able to multiply the price of a product in each line by the quantity, then add up all of the lines cost to figure out a "total cost". How would I be able to do it?

Here is the form:

[image: the form]

TL;DR How to multiply the price of a product for each line, then add up all of the total prices in each line. Thank you heaps!!

Here is my code: ***IGNORE OLEDB PART - SOME OF THE NAMING IS INCORRECT AS IT IS A WIP***

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmOrderProduct
    Dim iPadCasePrice As String
    Dim iPad2Price As String
    Dim prod_list As List(Of String)

    Private Sub frmOrderProduct_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        cmboxProduct.Items.Add("iPad Case")
        cmboxProduct.Items.Add("iPad 2")

        iPadCasePrice = "$20.00"
        iPad2Price = "$200.00"


        txtUsername.Text = frmLogin.txtUsername.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddToCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddToCart.Click

        If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "" Or txtQuantity.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill out all required fields", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid entered data")
        Else
            ListBoxCart.Items.Add("x" & txtQuantity.Text & " " & cmboxProduct.SelectedItem & " " & txtPriceEach.Text)

            'txtShoppingCart.AppendText("x" & txtQuantity.Text & " " & Product1 & Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtQuantity_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtQuantity.KeyPress

        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOrderProducts_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOrderProducts.Click

        Dim numberOfItems = ListBoxCart.Items.Count
        For Each item As String In ListBoxCart.Items

            Try

                cm = New OleDbCommand
                With cm
                    .Connection = cn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblOrders ([ProductName],[Quantity],[PriceEach],[TotalPrice],[Username]) VALUES (@ProductName,@Quantity,@PriceEach,@TotalPrice,@Username)"

                    prod_list = item.Split(" ").ToList
                    Dim prod_name = prod_list.ElementAt(1)
                    Dim prod_quantity = Integer.Parse(prod_list.ElementAt(0).Remove("x"))
                    Dim price_each = prod_list.ElementAt(2)

                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ProductName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, prod_name))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Quantity", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, prod_quantity))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@PriceEach", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, price_each))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TotalPrice", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, price_each))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, txtUsername.Text))
                    prod_list = New List(Of String)

                    cm.Parameters("@ProductName").Value = prod_name
                    cm.Parameters("@Quanity").Value = prod_quantity
                    cm.Parameters("@PriceEach").Value = price_each
                    cm.Parameters("@TotalPrice").Value =
                    cm.Parameters("@Username").Value = txtUsername.Text

                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = ""
                    txtQuantity.Text = ListBoxCart.Text = ""

                    Exit Sub
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClearCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearCart.Click

        ListBoxCart.Items.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmboxProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmboxProduct.SelectedIndexChanged

        If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "iPad Case" Then
            txtPriceEach.Text = iPadCasePrice
        End If

        If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "iPad 2" Then
            txtPriceEach.Text = iPad2Price
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: why don't you use 4 columns in the combo box.  first three for what is in the picture that you posted and the fourth for item total

Comment: True that could work, but I still would need to be able to add up the total cost in each line somehow. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: i just noticed that you used `vb.net` and `vba` tags ... you have to choose one. they are not interchangeable.

Comment: My aplogies! I will update that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Add a property for the total

```
Dim Total As Decimal
```

Then modify the `btnAddToCart_Click` and `btnClearCart_Click` to update it(I assume the name of the text box showing total is `txtTotal`)

```
Private Sub btnAddToCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddToCart.Click
    If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "" Or txtQuantity.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill out all required fields", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid entered data")
    Else
        ListBoxCart.Items.Add("x" & txtQuantity.Text & " " & cmboxProduct.SelectedItem & " " & txtPriceEach.Text)

        Dim q = Decimal.Parse(txtQuantity.Text)
        Dim p = Decimal.Parse(txtPriceEach.Text.Remove(0, 1)) 'need to remove the $ before parse
        Total += p * q
        txtTotal.Text = String.Format("${0}", Total)

        'txtShoppingCart.AppendText("x" & txtQuantity.Text & " " & Product1 & Environment.NewLine)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClearCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearCart.Click

    ListBoxCart.Items.Clear()
    Total = 0
    txtTotal.Text = String.Empty

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks heaps friend! Did exactly what I needed!!! Appreciate it so much <3 You're my savior

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a [`List(Of ...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) to the [`ListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) and sum up the items based on the list.

Here's an example with a list of [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx).

Of course you can create your own [`Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/walkthrough-defining-classes) and use it instead of [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
'Initialize a new list
Dim CartList As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, Decimal, Decimal))

'Add Items to the list (product-name, cost, quantity)
CartList.Add(New Tuple(Of String, Decimal, Decimal)("iPad Case", 20, 1))
CartList.Add(New Tuple(Of String, Decimal, Decimal)("iPad 2", 200, 2))

'Set the first item of the Tuple (the String) as DisplayMember
'(This will be the item-text shown inside the ListBox)
ListBoxCart.DisplayMember = "Item1"
ListBoxCart.ValueMember = "Item2"
ListBoxCart.DataSource = CartList 'Bind the list to the Listbox

Dim SumOfAllItems As Decimal

'Get the total of all items with Linq
'(This line calculates the sum of all items (cost * quantity)
'and assigns the value to the variable 'SumOfAllItems')
SumOfAllItems = ListBoxCart.Items.Cast(Of Tuple(Of String, Decimal, Decimal)).Sum(Function(itm) itm.Item2 * itm.Item3)

'Loop through the items in the list
'and print quantity, product-name and total to the console
For Each itm As Tuple(Of String, Decimal, Decimal) In CartList
    Console.WriteLine(itm.Item3 & "x " & itm.Item1 & " -> Total: " & (itm.Item2 * itm.Item3))
Next
```

**Note:**
After adding a new item to the list you have to re-bind the datasource of the listbox each time, otherwise the list won't refresh:

```
ListBoxCart.DataSource = CartList
```

Comment: Hey I saw your comment on another one of my questions suggesting to use this code. I have a question about it: What exactly does it do? I'm not a 100% sure what its doing so if you could explain what's going on I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: @EthanPayne It is just an example of how to bind a list of objects to the listbox and use the list/objects for calculation, instead of the concatenated strings of the listbox-items. I've added some links and comments to my post.